# when iterating over string python return None at the end

Tags: python

Let's consider a string:

```
s = 'abcdefghijl'
```

And a function that slices the string on a certain width:

```
def wrap(string,max_width):
    for i in range(0,len(string),max_width):
        print(string[i:i+max_width])

wrap(s,3)
```

Will print `None` in the last iteration because I will be out of bounds when slicing my string. Is there a way to work around this problem without creating a list comprehension like this:

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    return "\n".join([string[i:i+max_width] for i in range(0, len(string), max_width)])
```

Comment: That returns None because you aren't returning anything...

Comment: @JoanLaraGanau yap, hahaha :)

Comment: I mean printing. The last line will PRINT None

Comment: In my experiment, it just works fine(prints 'jl'). Try s[9:13], it is still 'jl'

Comment: How are you running the code that you see `None` printed? If your code is a script, it will not print the `None` because expression statements never print out when a script is running (or `print` would print `None` as well, since it returns `None` too!). If you're running the code in an interactive interpreter, you also shouldn't see `None` because that return value is usually suppressed by the REPL. I'd only expect you to see `None` printed out if you do `print(wrap(s,3))` (with the first version of the code).

Comment: prints None when testing the code on hacker-rank.com exercise

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini have a look at the [`grouper`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe from `itertools`. You can modify it according to your needs.

Comment: what python version did you use? I tried using python3.7 it work fine last iteration showing `jl`

Comment: it runs fine on my IDE too however when I define this function on hackerank it throws me an error saying the last line is None.

Comment: here is a link to the problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/text-wrap/problem

Answer (score 0):

I tested your function in Python 3.6:

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    return "\n".join([string[i:i+max_width] for i in range(0, len(string), max_width)])
```

and it works fine. Now, to get the printed version that you desire, you must call the function as follows:

```
print(wrap(s,3))
```

That will get you the expected result as listed in the website you linked.